# closing a program in wxpython via a menu item

Tags: python, wxpython

```
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):##main frame
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, size = (5000,5000)):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, size = (5000,5000))
        self.frame = parent

        Publisher().subscribe(self.showFrame, ("show.mainframe"))
    ##create menubar        
        menu=wx.MenuBar()
        file0 = wx.Menu()
        help0 = wx.Menu()
        rules = wx.Menu()
        Closed = file0.Append(wx.NewId(),"Quit")
        parent.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.close,Closed)

    def close(self,event):
        self.Close()
```

What I want to do is, when you press Quit from the menu item. It closed the whole progam but at the moment it doesn't seem to do anything.
How can i edit my code so it will close the whole program

Comment: Try self.frame.Close()

Comment: That worked :), put it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

@0x00mh solved this in the comments
`self.frame.Close()`